# convert integer seconds to equivalent three hours , minutes and seconds interger

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have an integer number as a variable. (this number can be any integer number).

Now I want to create a countdown timer based on this number on the page.

To create countDown, I am using [jquery-countdownTimer](http://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/) plugin.

A simple usage of this plugin is like this :

```
$(function(){
    $("#hms_timer").countdowntimer({
        hours : 3‚
        minutes : 10‚
        seconds : 10‚
        size : "lg"‚
        pauseButton : "pauseBtnhms"‚
        stopButton : "stopBtnhms"
    });
});
```

As you see , it gets hours , minutes and seconds in 3 separate numbers.

Now my question is how can I convert an integer number to Equivalent hours , minutes and seconds in simplest way?

Comment: I don't understand... To convert an hour to minutes, just multiply by 60. From minutes to seconds, multiply by 60 again. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: `new Date(1000* 3750 ).toISOString().split(/\D/).slice(3,6)` == `["01", "02", "30"]`

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getTime(s) {
  var secs = parseInt(s, 10); // don't forget the second param
  var hours = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
  var minutes = Math.floor((secs - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
  var seconds = secs - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

  return {
    hours: hours,
    minutes: minutes,
    seconds: seconds
  };
}

var time = getTime("3792");
alert("Hours: " + time.hours + "\nMinutes: " + time.minutes + "\nSeconds: " + time.seconds);
```